# Athena gzip compression query result has hybrid compressed-decompressed

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm setting AWS Athena with s3 bucket which has gzipped csv files.

And then query like this

`SELECT * FROM "sample_db"."sample_table2" limit 100;`

results is different take 1 and 2.

it seems like to mix compression / decompression results.

Is there any way getting result only decompressed result on Athena ?

file contents is below:

```
"title","user_info.client_user_id","user_info.player_id"
"test : csv take 4",,
"title","user_info.client_user_id","user_info.player_id"
"test : csv take 4",,
"title","user_info.client_user_id","user_info.player_id"
"test : csv take 4",,
"title","user_info.client_user_id","user_info.player_id"
"test : csv take 4",,
```

s3 has only one file `test-sample.gz`

Query Take 1
[image]

Query Take 2
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause is wrong format query, partitioning for csv and corrupted data.

It is working on directly s3 gz upload in directories.

Comment: for anyone who helps this issue, I recommend testing to move file to root, not directories.